# Parsing Vector to Array String

Tags: json, rust, websocket, serde

I'm new to Rust.

I try to write a websocket client.

This is my format message:

```
"[integer, "string", object]"
```

Is there away to store all value in Vector something like:

```
let msg: Vec<interface> = vec![123, "event", AnyObject{}];
```

How to convert it into string and vice versa.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conceptually speaking you want to use an enum. The type of enums used in rust are called tagged unions. Essentially you can think of them as enums which can hold data.

```rust
enum Interface {
    Int(i32),
    String(&'static str),
    Object(AnyObject),
    // etc
}

// You can then create a vec of different enum variants
let msg: Vec<Interface> = vec![Interface::Int(123), Interface::String("event"), Interface::Object(AnyObject{})];
```

Assuming you are referring to JSON, then the recommended solution is to use [`serde`](https://crates.io/crates/serde) with [`serde_json`](https://crates.io/crates/serde_json). `serde_json` provides a `Value` enum you can use to represent JSON data in an unknown layout.

```rust
// Copied from serde_json docs
enum Value {
    Null,
    Bool(bool),
    Number(Number),
    String(String),
    Array(Vec<Value>),
    Object(Map<String, Value>),
}
```

However, you don't need to use `Value` directly (unless you want to) since `serde_json` provides a macro to make this easier by letting you format your code like JSON.

```rust
use serde_json::{json, Value};

let msg: Value = json!([123, "event", {}]);

// You can then serialize a Value into JSON format
println!("{:?}", msg.to_string());
// Output: "[123,\"event\",{}]"
```

I recommend reading through the [overview](https://crates.io/crates/serde_json) since they have a bunch of convenient ways for working with JSON.